# How do I find the Item ID for products on eBay?

Tags: ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I am trying to use eBay's RESTful Sell API and Buy API to make an order management application. To test the API calls, I have successfully created seller and buyer accounts. Further, I have uploaded some inventory from my sellers account and published the offer.

Now I wish to place an order from the buyers account on the items in the same listing. From my understanding, I have to specify the items to be ordered by providing the Item IDs. However, I cannot figure out how to find the Item ID required for purchasing these items. Where can I find the Item ID's corresponding to an offer?

*In case this is not the correct approach and there is some alternate way to go about doing this, what steps am I required to take?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the `itemId` is the same as the `listingId`. The newer RESTful API's make use of the variable `listingId` to represent an identifier for a published listing. The same variable is referred to by the name `itemId` in the older, Trading APIs. The value for `listingId`/`itemId` is generated when publishing an offer and converting it into a listing. Thus, it can be fetched either at the time of publishing the offer (present in the response under the variable named `listingId`) or it can be fetched through an order (present in the response under the variable `legacyItemId`.